# How to put a block down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't know how to put a block down from inventory.  I have inventory but in the main playing screen, I don't know how to take an inventory item and put it down to start building a house.
I have already tried to do this, but all that happens is it smashes into the ground.

How do I use a block to start a house?

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Beginner%27s_guide

Comment: I wonder has @kcam seen the answer?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question, because I think it's fairly clear the user is asking how to place blocks in Minecraft. I don't think it's a good question, but that doesn't mean it should be closed.

Comment: @kcam There seems to be a lot of trolls and open-questions-and-never-login-again people on here quite alot. Not saying @ kcam is one, but it's very possible.

Answer (score 5):

**Do right click to place a block.**

---

If the right button of your mouse smashes, go to *Options > Controls*

and the **Use Item/Place Block** entry should be **Button 2**

Answer (score -1):

You can right click to place, and use the scroll wheel to select items.